# Problems with DisplayForModel

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have the following model:

```
namespace Storage.Models
{
    public class AdminDetail
    {
        public string PartitionKey { get; set; }
        public string RowKey { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Status { get; set; }
        public string Type { get; set; }
        public string Level { get; set; }

        public string Order { get; set; }
        public int Row { get; set; }
    }
```

I have the following code in my view:

```
@model IList<AdminDetail>

<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>@Html.LabelFor(x => x[0].Order)</th>
            <th>@Html.LabelFor(x => x[0].Order)</th>
            <th>@Html.LabelFor(x => x[0].Level)</th>
            <th>@Html.LabelFor(x => x[0].Title)</th>
            <th>@Html.LabelFor(x => x[0].Status)</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => item)
    }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

And in the file: Views\DisplayTemplates\AdminDetail.cshtml

```
    @model AdminDetail


xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
<tr>
    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Order)</td>
    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Level)</td>
    <td class="indent_@(adminDetail.Level)">@Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Title)</td>
    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Status)</td>
    <td>@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", 
            new { pk = adminDetail.PartitionKey, rk = adminDetail.RowKey },
            new { @class = "editLink" } )</td>    
    <td>@Ajax.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", "Menus",
            new { pk = adminDetail.PartitionKey, rk = adminDetail.RowKey },
            new AjaxOptions {
                        HttpMethod = "POST",
                        Confirm = "Are you sure you want to delete menu item ",
                        OnSuccess = "deleteConfirmation"
                    })</td>  
    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(x => x.PartitionKey) @Html.DisplayFor(x => x.RowKey)</td>
</tr>
```

When my view appears I see the data for the AdminDetails records but there is no formatting for `<tr>` and `<td>`  I also don't see any x's. I am using areas and the code for the view is inside an area. Is it possible that my code is not getting the DisplayTemplate because I am using areas?

Here's an example of the way data appears:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th><label for="">Order</label></th>
            <th><label for="">Order</label></th>

            <th><label for="">Level</label></th>
            <th><label for="">Title</label></th>
            <th><label for="">Status</label></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
<div class="display-label">PartitionKey</div>
<div class="display-field">01</div>
<div class="display-label">RowKey</div>
<div class="display-field">02</div>
<div class="display-label">Title</div>
<div class="display-field">Test55</div>
<div class="display-label">Status</div>
<div class="display-field">New</div>
<div class="display-label">Type</div>
<div class="display-field"></div>
<div class="display-label">Level</div>
<div class="display-field"></div>
```

Comment: Sorry. I put in <tr> and <td> in the question but it didn't appear. Just edited and put those as code. Data appears but it seems there is no formatting and it's not looking at my template.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The path to your display template is wrong. Instead of:

```
Views\DisplayTemplates\AdminDetail.cshtml
```

you should use:

```
Views\Shared\DisplayTemplates\AdminDetail.cshtml
```

Notice the `Shared` bit. It could also be:

```
Views\XXX\DisplayTemplates\AdminDetail.cshtml
```

where `XXX` is the name of the current controller if you want this display template to be available only for this controller.

Also replace your loop:

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    @Html.DisplayFor(model => item)
}
```

with its equivalent:

```
@Html.DisplayForModel()
```

You don't need to loop. Since your model is a collection, ASP.NET MVC will automatically invoke your display template for each element of this collection.

Comment: Ohh I missed the Shared, deleted mine.

Comment: "where XXX is the name of the current controller" that was it. Thanks!